# How to pass / store secrets in Azure DevOps Services that can be accessed from unit test

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, vstest

I need to use secret passwords in unit tests execution that are retrieved from Environmental Variables.

Tests are executed by Visual Studio Test task in version 2.*

```
_networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DomainAccountUsername"), Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DomainAccountPassword"));
```

If I set DomainAccountPassword directly from Powershell everything works fine, test ends successfully, but I don't want to show password to other users in my team.

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DomainAccountPassword;]MyExamplePassword"
```

Passing secret defined in Library Group does not work, causing authentication error.

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DomainAccountPassword;]$(secretPassword)"
```

How can I pass secret to VSTS task so it can authenticate in external API?

Thank You!

Comment: When you say Library Group do you mean the variable has been set in Devops Under `Library > Variable groups?`

Comment: Exactly, this variable group is linked to my release pipeline. I have also tried to use release variable defined for one stage in release pipeline.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### As per [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#secret-variables)

> Secret variables are encrypted at rest with a 2048-bit RSA key. Secrets are available on the agent for tasks and scripts to use (so be careful about who has access to alter your pipeline).
>
> **...**
>
> Unlike a normal variable, they are not automatically decrypted into environment variables for scripts. You can explicitly map them in, though.
>
> To pass a secret to a script, use the Environment section of the scripting task's input variables.

### To use secrets in scripts

Set the variable to secret:
[image]

Pass the variable to the script explicitly
[image]

And use the new env var in your script by name `$env:topshelfPassword`

### If your pipeline is YAML and not in the Classic Editor

> You should not set secret variables in your YAML file. Instead, you should set them in the pipeline editor using the web interface. These variables are scoped to the pipeline in which you set them.
>
> The following example shows how to pass a secret variable called mySecret set in the web interface to a script.

YAML

```ps
steps:

- powershell: |
    # Using an input-macro:
    Write-Host "This works: $(mySecret)"

    # Using the env var directly:
    Write-Host "This does not work: $env:MYSECRET"

    # Using the mapped env var:
    Write-Host "This works: $env:MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR"    # Recommended
  env:
    MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $(mySecret)
```

Notice how the variable is declared in the web ui as `mySecret` and what would work for a typical non-secret variable (`$env:mySecret`) doesn't b/c it's a secret. However, what works in YAML that doesn't work in the Classic experience (I believe I'm correct) is the use of "input-macro" syntax (`$(mySecret)`).

Comment: I didn't include in my screenshot that `.topshelfPassword` is consumed by scoped variables `dev.topshelfPassword` and `prod.topshelfPassword` because this is in a release pipeline, but I think the idea should be easily known.

Comment: I suppose problem is with Visual Studio Test task

For example in Cake task I can pass secret as environmental variable

steps:
- task: cake-build.cake.cake-build-task.Cake@0
  displayName: 'Deploy'
  inputs:
    script: deploy.cake
    arguments: '--Pass=$(SecretPass)'

In release pipeline task Visual Studio Test there is no property "env" or "arguments" there is only property "otherConsoleOptions" that allows to pass arguments mentioned below
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2019 
Am I wrong or right here?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Visual Studio Test task cannot get secret in runtime as environmental variable but it can accept secret set as parameter from TestContext

```
_networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DomainAccountUsername"), TestContext.Parameters["DomainAccountPassword"]);
```

I have added .runsettings file to test project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <TestRunParameters>
    <Parameter name="DomainAccountPassword" value="" />
  </TestRunParameters>
</RunSettings>
```

And in Visual Studio Test task options I have set path to settings file and overrided DomainAccountPassword parameter with my secret.

[Visual Studio Test task options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QFzV.png)